# numeric type parse functions exception with negative numbers

Tags: java, integer, hex, parseint

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("7FFFFFFF", 16)); //this is ok.
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("FFFFFFFF", 16)); //this throws Exception
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf("FFFFFFFF", 16)); //this throws Exception
```

When I try to convert hexadecimal number to integer type, negative numbers with parseInt or valueOf methods, the method throws NumberFormatException for negative numbers. I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: FFFFFFFF is out of range of Integer I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt()` and `Integer.valueOf()` expect the minus sign (`-`) for negative values.

Hence "FFFFFFFF" is parsed as a positive value, which is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Hence the exception.

If you want to parse it as a negative value, parse it as `long` and cast to `int`:

```
System.out.println((int)Long.parseLong("FFFFFFFF", 16));
```

prints

```
-1
```

Answer (score 2):

`Integer.parseInt("FFFFFFFF", 16)` doesn't mean "give me the `int` with this hexadecimal bit pattern". It means "interpret `FFFFFFFF` as a base-16 representation of a number, and give me an `int` representing the same number".

That number is the *positive* number 4294967295, which is out of range for an `int`, hence the exception.